# Does Spring Security have a 'hasAllRole' that performs the AND version of 'hasAnyRole'

Tags: spring, grails, spring-security, spring-el

I'm using Spring Security in Grails to restrict access to my controllers.  I have a use case where I want to check that a user has multiple roles assigned.  I realize I could just make another role that is synonymous with 'person has these two roles', but it would require much more changes than I'd like.

Spring Security has an OR version [expression](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/el-access.html) to check if a user has any of a list of roles:

```
//allow user to access if he has role ROLE_ADMIN -OR- ROLE_USER
//note this is shortcut notation for hasAnyRole(["ROLE_ADMIN","ROLE_USER"])
@Secured(["ROLE_ADMIN","ROLE_USER"])
def index = {}
```

Is there a method, or just way using [Spring Expression Language (SpEL)](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html) to do the following:

```
//allow user to access if he has role ROLE_ADMIN -AND- ROLE_USER
@Secured("hasAllRole(['ROLE_ADMIN','ROLE_USER']")
def index = {}
```

Note:  SpringSecurityUtils class does have the method

```
public static boolean ifAllGranted(final String roles)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `@PreFilter` instead of `@Secured` then you can write:

```
@PreFilter("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN') and hasRole('ROLE_USER')")
```

Answer (score 3):

```
hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN') and hasRole('ROLE_USER')
```

Couldn't be much simpler

Comment: Are you sure that @Secured support that syntax?

Comment: The doc linked by the OP shows that the annotation to use is PreAuthorize.

Comment: But I expect, it will not work for @Secured. Its Java Doc and all examples that I found use roles directly, but no expressions!

Comment: Yes indeed. I assumed the OP would be able to find the appropriate annotation, since he knows where to look for in the documentation.

Comment: In giving an answer you should probably not make an assumption like that.  It's best I think to mention that it doesn't work for @Secured since this was the a core part of the question posed.

Answer (score 1):

could you not do `hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN') and hasRole('ROLE_USER')`?